# Access specified columns from .mat file in python

Tags: python, scipy, glob

I have a total of 61225 matrices each having the same variable names with different data. I am interested only in the file having variable name `Pose_Para` this is a `1x7` file out of which I am only interested in the 2nd,3rd and 4th column. My problem is how do I access these columns only so that I obtain a matrix with size `[61225 x 3]`?

Here is what I have done till now.

```
import glob
from scipy.io import loadmat
    
entries = glob.glob('300W_LP/*/*.mat', recursive=True)
print(len(entries))
for entry in entries:
    para = loadmat(entry, variable_names = ("Pose_Para",))["Pose_Para"]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you're a MATLAB user; if you are you may find this invaluable: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm presuming that `para = loadmat(entry, variable_names = ("Pose_Para",))["Pose_Para"]` results in `para` being a 7-element numpy array. If that's the case, you can do:

```
import numpy as np

# ...file handling...
allparas = np.empty((len(entries),3))
for ctr,entry in enumerate(entries):
    allparas[ctr,:] = loadmat(entry, variable_names = ("Pose_Para",))["Pose_Para"][1:3]
```

Note that you might need to add `squeeze_me = True` to your `loadmat` call. I'm not sure if `loadmat` needs this to yield a 7-element 1D Numpy array as opposed to a 1x7 2D array.

You could also use a list comprehension to write the for loop as a one-liner:

```
allparas = np.array([loadmat(entry, variable_names= ("Pose_Para",))["Pose_Para"][1:3] for entry in entries])
```

Comment: I posted this question whilst the code was still running, I expected para to be [61225x7] but actually I only got [1x7] do you maybe know why the matrices were over-written?

Comment: Are you asking why your original code resulted in one [1x7] array? It's because you are overwriting `para` in each iteration of your loop.

Comment: Ok would that be because I did not use `enumerate(entries)`? Only asking because I am trying to figure out what I did wrong

Comment: `enumerate` is one way to deal with it, you could also have initialized a blank list and called `.append(...)` on it, there are multiple ways to add data to a data structure as you iterate through. The most pythonic is probably the list comprehension, but enumerate is probably the most intuitive to someone new to python.